# Installing h5py on 64 bit Windows

Tags: windows, python-2.7, h5py

I'm trying to install h5py onto a 64 Windows 7 system.  In the past I've had success using the wheel files at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
Unfortunately the 64 bit version does not seem to be available.  I get the following error.

Downloading/unpacking h5py-2.6.0-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
  Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement h5py-2.6.0-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
No distributions at all found for h5py-2.6.0-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl

It looks like there were Windows installers for h5py version 2.5, however those are 32 bit.  I'd be happy with version 2.5 if there is a 64 bit install.

I'm using ActiveState python 2.7 distribution.  It looks like one of the other distributions like Anaconda might support it, but I'd rather not reinstall everything if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up moving to the Anaconda distribution.  It came with everthing I needed including h5py.